# How to Use Java Data Structures?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Given a zipcode and movieName the function will return list of theatres with the corresponding MovieName and zipcode?

Approach I followed:

Create two tables theatres and films and Store the data there.

```
Table:
theatres:                                 films     
SNO TheatreName                           SNO zipcode Moviename
1   Hari                                   1  180004  Transporter
1   Habitz                                 2  180010  Mi Impossible
2   Shakuntala
```

During Startup i will fetch the details from the database and put it in hashmap.
My Hashmap will contains films object and corresponding list of all theatres.So When i retrieve given films object,it will give collection of all theatres.

Will this be the correct approach?
The only problem with this approach is we have to maintain seperate lists theatrename for all the SNO which will consume memory.
Can anyone please tell me the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

One theatre can have many movies. One movie can be running in many theatres. But both movie and theatre can exist independently of each other. I would create a mapping table between Theatre and Movie.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in cases like yours, the better approach would be to create these relations that you have on a database level rather than code level, you can simply add  a third table to break this Many-To-Many relationship that you have here.

```
Film-Theater
FSNO   TSNO
1      1
1      2
```

now the complexity is in getting this data from the DB rather the Code design complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are two misconceptions in your solution.

1. You put the `zipcode` field in the `films` table. A zip code is related to a theatre, not a movie! This is more obvious when you realize that a movie can be displayed in several places with distinct zip codes.
2. As others already mentioned, several movies are available in a theater and a movie can be watched in several theaters. The best way to modelize it is to create a third table

Tables

```
theatres:                   films:                         program:
id   TheatreName            id     zipcode Moviename       filmId  theatreId
1    Hari                   1      180004  Transporter     1       1
2    Habitz                 2      180010  Mi Impossible   1       2
3    Shakuntala                                            2       3
```

3. Moreover, I suspect that you are using the Hasmaps to link you tables. You should better use an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) in your SQL query. Even if you don't do that putting your whole database in HashMaps can be a bad idea if your DB is big. (Sorry if I am wrong about this point ;) )

Comment: Thanks,but i put the mapping in such a way that i can use zipcode with moviename as key to retrieve collection of theatres.Imagine if the entries are small and we can cache easily in code,then what approach we will use to retrieve all theatres.

Comment: @pankaj HashMap would work but I would make a query for that since it is simpler

Comment: Yes but I have to create a seperate list of theatres with a specific ID to be used as a value in Hashmap corresponding to zipcode and moviname as a key.Will this be correct to use a new list as value for every key?